# Write to excel using Apache POI. FileNotFoundException:(The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi

Can anyone help shine any light into this?  I am trying to write an array of data to excel to the next empty line from a selenium test script.  My code works for generating the excel the first execution, writes the data properly, but then on second execution (in the same application run), and follow-up executions throws the following:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: TestResultData2.xls (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
```

After some hours of attempts and searching I found this may be related to a Windows issue (see: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58480) but am not sure if I am missing something remedial.. Most other searches show that this may be caused from not closing the FileOutputStream but it is so I am confused there.
Please see the following exportDataToExcel method. Note I have tried many different methods but this is my most recent/most tested attempt.

```
public static void exportDataToExcel(String fileName, String tabName, String[][] data) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, Exception
  {
    //Create new workbook and tab
    Workbook wb;
    File newFile = new File(fileName);
    Sheet sheet = null;

    if (newFile.exists()) { 
           // Load existing
           wb = WorkbookFactory.create(newFile);
    }else {
           if (newFile.getName().endsWith(".xls")) {
               wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
           }else {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown file type. Please use .xls");
           }
    }
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

    // Check if the workbook is empty or not
    if (wb.getNumberOfSheets() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
           if (wb.getSheetName(i).equals(tabName)) {
               sheet = wb.getSheet(tabName);
           }else sheet = wb.createSheet(tabName);
        }
    }else {
        // Create new sheet to the workbook if empty
        sheet = wb.createSheet(tabName);
    }

      //Create 2D Cell Array
      Row[] row = new Row[data.length];
      Cell[][] cell = new Cell[row.length][];
      //Define and Assign Cell Data from Given
      for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i ++)
      {           
          row[i] = sheet.createRow(i);  
          cell[i] = new Cell[data[i].length];

          for(int j = 0; j < cell[i].length; j ++)
          {
              cell[i][j] = row[i].createCell(j);
              cell[i][j].setCellValue(data[i][j]);
          }
      }

      //Export Data
      wb.write(fileOut);
      fileOut.close();
      wb.close();
      System.out.println("File exported successfully");

  }
```

I am calling the method via:

```
String data[][]= {{cpAppFN, cpAppLN, cpAppDOB, cpAppSSN}};
exportDataToExcel("TestResultData2.xls", "Results2", data);
```

Stacktrace below, for reference.

`Test_ConsumerPortal Line 210 is FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(newFile);` and `Line 142 is exportDataToExcel("TestResultData2.xls", "Results2", data);` within the test itself.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: TestResultData2.xls (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at tests.Test_ConsumerPortal.exportDataToExcel(Test_ConsumerPortal.java:210)
at tests.Test_ConsumerPortal.Execution(Test_ConsumerPortal.java:142)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


java.io.FileNotFoundException: TestResultData2.xls (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at tests.Test_ConsumerPortal.exportDataToExcel(Test_ConsumerPortal.java:210)
at tests.Test_ConsumerPortal.Execution(Test_ConsumerPortal.java:142)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

If there is any other information needed please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `wb = WorkbookFactory.create(newFile)` is called, internally a `FileInputStream` is created. Without closing the `FileInputStream`, you are calling calling `FileOutputStream` in `FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(newFile);`.

When you are creating the workbook, WorkbookFactory.create(newFile)` does not come into play and so the first attempt passes. It is in subsequent attempts that the mentioned code path is hit and the code breaks.

The solution is to open a `FileInputStream` if the file exists and then pass it onto `create()`. After you are done updating the values in the excel sheet, close the `FileInputStream` and open the `FileOutputStream` for writing the new data.

Below code should work as is.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class ExcelDataUpdater {

    public static void exportDataToExcel(String fileName, String tabName, String[][] data)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, Exception {
        // Create new workbook and tab
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        Workbook wb;
        Sheet sheet = null;

        // Check the file extension
        if (!fileName.endsWith(".xls")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown file type. Please use .xls");
        }

        File newFile = new File(fileName);

        // If file not exists we create a new workbook
        if (!newFile.exists()) {
            wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        } else {
            // If file exists, we open an input stream channel to it
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(newFile);
            // Provide the input stream to WorkbookFactory
            wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        }

        // Check if the workbook is empty or not
        boolean isSheetFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            if (wb.getSheetName(i).equals(tabName)) {
                sheet = wb.getSheet(tabName);
                isSheetFound = true;
            }
        }
        if (!isSheetFound) {
            sheet = wb.createSheet(tabName);
        }

        // Create 2D Cell Array
        Row[] row = new Row[data.length];
        Cell[][] cell = new Cell[row.length][];
        // Define and Assign Cell Data from Given
        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            row[i] = sheet.createRow(i);
            cell[i] = new Cell[data[i].length];

            for (int j = 0; j < cell[i].length; j++) {
                cell[i][j] = row[i].createCell(j);
                cell[i][j].setCellValue(data[i][j]);
            }
        }

        // If file already exists, we had opened an input stream.
        // We will close this here
        if (inputStream != null)
            inputStream.close();

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

        // Export Data
        wb.write(outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
        wb.close();
        System.out.println("File exported successfully");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws InvalidFormatException, EncryptedDocumentException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception {
        String data1[][] = { { "A", "B", "C", "D" } };
        ExcelDataUpdater.exportDataToExcel("TestResultData2.xls", "Results1", data1);

        String data2[][] = { { "X", "Y", "Z", "W" } };
        ExcelDataUpdater.exportDataToExcel("TestResultData2.xls", "Results2", data2);
    }
}
```

I have also optimized the code for checking whether the sheet exists and creating sheet.

Comment: This fixed the error.  Thank you for the gracious explanation of the inputstream I didn't know about, and cleaning up the sheet check.  Probably should be a separate question but for anyone in the future who sees this and wonders why it may still replace the same line instead of adding to new line, simply replace `row[i] = sheet.createRow(i);
` with `int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
         row[i] = sheet.createRow(rowCount+1);`

Comment: Glad to be of help